# Using json file as an array

Tags: python, json

I'm making a program that gets a json file from a url, then choses a random property and gives the value

My code is

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request
import json
import random

url = Request("url", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
serial = json.loads(data)

product_finder = input("Type of product to generate? (Headset, Keyboard, etc.): ").lower()
if product_finder == "headsets" or "headset":
    product = "headset"



def generate():
    return "".join([random.choice(list(serial[product]['rowin']))])

print(generate())
```

this is my json file

```
{

  "headset": {
      "test": "1, 2, 3"

  },

  "keyboard": {

  },

  "mouse": {

  },

  "racing": {

  },

  "misc": {

  }
}
```

Now for the `return` statement I'd want it to return either `1`, `2`, or `3`. Now it also returns the commas. is there a way to make this not happen and sort of treat it as an array

Comment: You realized `test` is just a string?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval("1, 2, 3")` -> `(1, 2, 3)` (a tuple of values)

Comment: or if you're in charge of the server too, then change "1,2,3" to [1,2,3] in the response..JSON supports int arrays.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
def generate():
    return "".join([random.choice((serial[product]['test']).split(', '))])
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you.